# Nested parameters in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two models:- a) A b) B

model A looks like this:-

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :bs ,:dependent => :destroy   
validates :name, :presence=>true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :bs
attr_accessible :bs_attributes

end
```

model B looks like this

```
class PlanDay < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :a
attr_accessible :a_attributes

end
```

In my view I have used form_for and fields_for, but I am confused in the parameter that I am  getting:-

```
 Parameters: {"a"=>{"name"=>"swsdw" , "bs_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"friday"=>"true", "wednesday"=>"", "tuesday"=>"", "sunday"=>"true", "saturday"=>"true", "monday"=>"", "thursday"=>""}}
```

What is this 0 I am getting in bs_attributes? Is this the reason that I am not able to save the values of my days in 'bs' table?

I am saving this as follow:-
     @a = A.new(params[:a])

and this is saving my both the models are getting saved , but the all the days that are present in parameters are getting saved with null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` has a `has_many` relationship with `B`. So, the `bs_attributes` will actually be an array containing multiple `Bs`. So, `0` means the first `B`. If you had passed two `Bs`, then there would have been `0` as above and an additional hash beginning with `1`.

I dont think the `0` is causing `B` to have null values. And `0` is not causing a problem because you are able to save multiple `bs` when saving `A`.

You stated "I am saving this as follow:- `@a = A.new(params[:a])"`. Did you not save `@a` or you forgot to include it in your question ? Add `@a.save!` after that. The bang(`!`) will show you the failed validations if `@a` is not saved.